# What is the meaning of the 2 in calculating the length of a substring as "(right-left+2)"?

Tags: c

I am designing a program in C to detect tokens.

I got confused in the 4th line. What does the `(right-left+2)` do?

```
char* sub_string(char* str, int left, int right)
{
    int i;
    char* sub_str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(right-left+2)); /* 4th line */
}
```

Comment: It's pretty straightforward math being used to determine how much memory to dynamically allocate.

Comment: However, nothing is ever done with that memory, so it's hard to say what the purpose of this code is except to cause a memory leak.

Comment: @Chris - at least a leak is something .... may not be desired, but it's something `:)`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I do not get the significance/benefit of your edit...

Answer (score 2):

`right-left+2` in this case would be `right-left+1+1`.
Where `righ-left` would be the length from left to right, but without counting the left one. Hence one +1.
The other +1 is for making one additional character of space, most likely for adding a 0 termination.

By the way, the function is missing a clean `return` statement.

E.g. (thanks David C. Ranking for the idea of an example) `"this"` within `"more this than that"`:

```
more this than that
0    5  8
```

The `'t'` is at `left` 5, the `'s'` is at `right` 8. The length of `"this"` is clearly 4 (not counting the, absent, 0 terminator). But 8-5 is only 3. So use one `+1` to include the additional character (by my counting the `'t'` is missing...).

If that substring is to be returned via a pointer to  malloced memory, which is what I guess the (missing) rest of the function is supposed to do; it should include the 0-terminator in the malloced memory. That needs another character of memory to be malloced; by using the second `+1`.

Comment: Simple examples help. Take the substring `left = 2` and `right = 3`. There are 2 characters there, but `3 - 2 = 1`. So as Yunnosch says, you add `+1` to make the range inclusive. Then every C-string must the nul-terminated with `'\0'` (just plain `0` is fine), so that's another `+1`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is nice. If you do not use that to make a (better) answer, please allow me to copy and attribute it into mine.

Comment: Goes to show that it might be easier to understand if the substring were specified as start index and length.

Comment: I think the "upvote" on my comment addressed at David is the permission. But just in case that not, I only used the very appreciated spirit, without strictly copying.

Comment: @Yunnosch - feel free. You got my vote and comment and are free to use both `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, I thought so. But I am quite happy with the example I created. It still has visible traces of your appreciated input of course.